# Google Sheets - Trying to use IMPORTRANGE to get student enrollments by school by date

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I made columns that simply lists all the schools for each student under a date column header. I only need to count the schools - I don't want to see any student data. I have a form that needs to be submitted to the state and there is a cell with the date we are submitting.  I want to use an IMPORTRANGE to go to the other spreadsheet and find the column where the date matches the form date and pull back the count of schools in that column. I tried using INDEX/MATCH, etc., and while I have those working on the form for other data already on my spreadsheet - I can't seem to get them to work on the 'outside' spreadsheet.  Any help is appreciated!  I'm attaching an example spreadsheet with more explanation.  I hope it's clear.  Thank you.

[Example Document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1i_0bSTZ9-SdQyLkvkNfVlS6SXDKUKakw-5JGhUvguU4/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: New file with IMPORTRANGE and example of report and the FINAL number I'm trying to get to.    https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1igi2lQGrBQqAaT4sHClzoR-r6R3y1Rl86Zs9qzeqhZs/edit#gid=886136610

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ztiaa has provided a good solution. I will suggest another which pivots the data differently. I feel that having the dates go across columns is going to quickly become unwieldy. So this approach leaves the dates running down the right side with the schools running as column headers. My solution also *includes* exceptions such as snow days, as those will likely be important to see at a glance as well. Just be careful to use the same notation for such exceptions. For instance, *always* use "snowday" (not, eg., "snow day") or "prep day" (not, e.g., "prep").

In Sheet1, use IMPORTRANGE to bring in the data exactly as you have it listed in your sample sheet (i.e., dates at top, school names or exceptions under each date header).

Then, in a *new sheet*, place the following formula in cell A1:

`=ArrayFormula({QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!1:1&"~"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!1:1<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 FORMAT Col1 'mmm dd'"),TRANSPOSE({"District Totals",MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!1:1<>"")="",0,1))})})`

This assumes that the first sheet is, in fact, named `Sheet1`. If it is not, you'll need to change every instance of that sheet name in the formula.

It will probably further aid visual ease if you freeze Row 1 and Column 1 (**View > Freeze > 1 row / 1 column**).

**ADDENDUM** (after seeing realistic copy of OP's sheet)

`=ArrayFormula({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!1:1&"~"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 FORMAT Col1 'mmm dd'"));{"District Totals",MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")<>"",1,0))}})`

If you prefer to see the name of the exception (e.g., "snowday") rather than the count of 1 for each exception in the "District totals" line:

`=ArrayFormula({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!1:1&"~"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 FORMAT Col1 'mmm dd'"));{"District Totals",IF(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")<>"",1,0))=1,FILTER(Sheet1!2:2,Sheet1!2:2<>""),MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")<>"",1,0)))}})`

If you want exceptions (e.g., "snowday") to always appear at the bottom instead of in alphabetical order within the school-name list:

`=ArrayFormula({TRANSPOSE(QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!1:1&"~"&IF(REGEXMATCH(UPPER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A))),INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A))),,"‡")&INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null AND Col2 <> '‡' GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 FORMAT Col1 'mmm dd'"));{"District Totals",IF(MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")<>"",1,0))=1,FILTER(Sheet1!2:2,Sheet1!2:2<>""),MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!2:2<>"")<>"",1,0)))}})`

Comment: Erik - thank you for your response.  I entered this into column A1 on Sheet2, and left the first sheet as Sheet1; however, it give me a #REF with this error: Error
Function ARRAY_ROW parameter 2 has mismatched row size. Expected: 7. Actual: 8.  I'm not sure what that means.  Also, I agree that dates going across become unwieldy quickly! However, that is what I have to work with for this project. My biggest issue, is I need to know how to use this using an IMPORTRANGE function.  I cannot load the actual spreadsheet as it is filled with student data.  Thank you again, Karen.

Comment: If you want the other orientation (with dates across the top), we'd just wrap the whole thing in TRANSPOSE (or at least that is the easiest way): `=ArrayFormula(TRANSPOSE({QUERY(SPLIT(FLATTEN(FILTER(Sheet1!1:1&"~"&INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!1:1<>"")),"~",1,0),"Select Col1, COUNT(Col1) WHERE Col2 Is Not Null GROUP BY Col1 PIVOT Col2 FORMAT Col1 'mmm dd'"),TRANSPOSE({"District Totals",MMULT(SEQUENCE(1,ROWS(Sheet1!A2:A),1,0),IF(FILTER(INDIRECT("Sheet1!2:"&ROWS(Sheet1!A:A)),Sheet1!1:1<>"")="",0,1))})}))`

Comment: It is always difficult to try to solve a problem one cannot see. As far as what is in your sample spreadsheet, the formulas provided work in my copy of that sheet. HOWEVER... if you are leaving all of your notes in Sheet1, then, yes, that may be causing the problem, because the formula counts headers, and you have notes in header columns. Delete the notes and that may solve the issue. As to IMPORTRANGE, you would just use IMPORTRANGE in Sheet1 to bring in the data as shown in your sample spreadsheet. Sheet2 would act on that data.

Comment: Erik - I agree about not seeing the 'real' thing.  I'm going to try and attach another document that I skinnied up to get rid of data - but is much closer to show what I'm ultimately trying to get at. Your suggestion to do the IMPORTRANGE - thank youl You'll see on the sheet, that is what I did. And when I removed those lines you mentioned - your formula did work on the original example sheet.  However, on this sheet I'm sending (with the IMPORTRANGE, I couldn't get either formula to work. In the end, I'm just trying to get to one number that matches the date!  Thank you!

Comment: Thanks, seeing the actual data helped greatly. Your sample sheet only had dates running as far as you had data in columns. Your real sheet has dates running through the end of the school year with blanks delineating months. That made a big difference. Try the formula under the newly added **ADDENDUM** portion of my post. (Your data set, though mostly blank now, is quite large, so it may take a few seconds for the formula to populate.)

Comment: Thank you so much Erik! I can't say I understand everything in the formula, and I plan to study it more; but for now it's giving me what I need to move forward.  Many, many thanks!!!

Comment: You're welcome. I should say that this kind of custom, time-intensive, complex formula writing is not typical of these volunteer-run forums. I say this only to set realistic expectations (for your future use, for other site visitors who may see this, for the volunteer contributor community, and for myself). But I was happy to provide this level of solution for you currently.

Comment: I think it's good to mention that, and this forum is lucky to have you. I just spent hours on this formula: =INDEX(SummaryTab!B2:EG6,MATCH($E$5,SummaryTab!A2:A6,0),MATCH($C$2,SummaryTab!B1:EG1,0)) and a few others -  which are so simple compared to yours! I ended up using the third that you posted, and I meant to thank you also for the choices. It's easy to see you have experience and vision to know what others could use. I really can't say thank you enough - you made this possible! I've taken Ben Collins Advanced Formulas course, which is very helpful, but I'm not ready for what you wrote! :)

Comment: I say this a lot, that anyone who knows anything about anything learned it essentially the same way: from scratch and one piece at a time. So keep learning, taking things apart, putting them back together. We are *all* still learning (at least if we are doing life right).

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

`=ArrayFormula({query(split(flatten(text(A1:E1,"mmm/d")&"❄️"&A2:E),"❄️"),"select Col2, count(Col2) where not Col2 matches '|Snowday' group by Col2 pivot Col1");{"District Total",transpose(MMult(transpose(N(filter(A2:E,not(RegexMatch(A2:E2,"Snowday")))<>"")),sequence(rows(A2:E))^0))}})`
[image]

Comment: Thank you ztiaa.  I'm trying to use an IMPORTRANGE to pull in that grid data from another workbook. I tried adjusting your formula to pull from that other workbook, but I'm not sure where to put the IMPORTRANGE.  It works perfectly on what you sent me. Do you know how to basically wrap what you gave me into an IMPORTRANGE function? I can adjust the column references as needed.  Thanks again!  Karen

Comment: Hi, If we call the importrange directly in the formula it will get very slow as we would need multiple calls.  The best way to do this is to create a new tab in the final sheet and run the importrange there, then adjust the ranges based on the imported data.